# Jquery-UI sortable tooltip opacity

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip, opacity, jquery-ui-sortable

I have created a list of sortable tables between several ULs.  I have so that the sortable LI's have a tooltip (ui-tooltip) that shows up on hover.  But when it shows up, it has an opacity of about 50-70%, where I can still see the text of the other LIs behind the tooltip window, though I can't see the borders of the LI's behind it.  I have gone through the css files of jQuery-UI and played with the opacity settings in the three files, jquery-ui.css, jquery-ui.structure.css, and jquery-ui.theme.css, setting opacity: 1 or to 100 for IE8 options.  I did look on the jQuery-UI themeroller to see if there were any settings for the tooltip there, but had no luck.  Anyone have ideas on where to get it so that the tooltip doesn't show the text behind it?

---

added code here to question

Well, maybe it's not exactly a jQuery-UI tooltip, now that I've played a round with it a bit.  Here's an entry of a UL:

```
            <ul id="sortList1" class="sortable sortListEntryArea">
                <li class="ui-state-default sortableCSS sortableBucket" id="competency6" competencyName="Technical Credibility">
                    <div>
                        <div id="div0" class="competencyCount"></div>
                        <div class="competencyName">
                            <span class="ui-tooltip" id="competency0Title" title="">
                                Technical Credibility 2
                                <span>
                                    Understands and appropriately applies principles, procedures, requirements, regulations, and policies
                                    related to specialized expertise. Remains current with technology, tools, trends, and evolving practices
                                    in area of expertise.
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li> 
                <li class="ui-state-default sortableCSS sortableBucket" id="competency7" competencyName="Strategic Thinking">
                    <div>
                        <div id="div1" class="competencyCount"></div>
                        <div class="competencyName">
                            <span class="ui-tooltip" id="competency1Title" title="">
                                Strategic Thinking 2
                                <span>
                                    Formulates goals, objectives and priorities that facilitate achievement of the organizational vision.
                                    Implements plans consistent with the long-term interests of the organization in a global environment
                                    that takes into consideration the environment, resources, capabilities, constraints, and organizational
                                    goals and values. Capitalizes on opportunities and manages risks and contingencies, recognizing the
                                    implications for the organization and stakeholders.
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>
```

then here is the css that helps to make it work , ... I think ... :

```
li.sortableCSS span span{
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-width:1px;
    z-index: 6;
    width: 275px;
    opacity: 1;
}


li.sortableCSS:hover span span{
    left: 2%;
    background: #dfdfdf;
    margin: 22px 0 0 0;
    z-index:6;
    width: 275px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It seems to have something to do with my adding the ui-tooltip as a class to the hidden span.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding how tooltip works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually go and overwrite the jQuery tooltip css. You can do that with the following css:

```
.tooltip {
 opacity:0.8;
 /* for IE */
 filter:alpha(opacity=80);     
}
```

If you want to create custom CSS classes for your tooltip to use, you could define your custom CSS classes, and then assign them to your tooltip like so:

```
(".selector").tooltip {
extraClass:"customCssClass"
}
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by overriding the default css of the class **ui-widget-shadow** (set up in jquery-ui.css) which is giving the whole tooltip div an opacity of 0.3.

I added in my own css file :

```
.ui-widget-shadow {
    opacity: 1;
}
```